# Загадки MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Почему так выводит:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    echo "$row[id]\t\t\t$row[text]\t\t\t$row[date]<br>";
}
```

а если так, то два раза не выводит:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    echo "$row[id]\t\t\t$row[text]\t\t\t$row[date]<br>";
}
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    echo "$row[id]\t\t\t$row[text]\t\t\t$row[date]<br>";
}
```

Смысл же один.... Почему?

Comment: @mkrichet1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: семачки закончились)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что первый while уже перебрал все результаты.

Comment: И что делать? Как повторно вызвать???

Comment: @mkrichet1, сбросить результаты в массив или повторить запрос к БД.

Comment: @Ale_x ого, я думал что такого нет, что БД сама фетчит по записи и передает, поэтому отмотать ее нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

[[@Etki](/users/16095/etki)](/users/16095/etki), вроде [mysql_data_seek()](http://www.php.su/functions/?mysql-data-seek) служит для таких целей, просто установить внутренний указатель в ноль.

Answer (score 0):

```
$r2 = $r;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo "$row[id]\t\t\t$row[text]\t\t\t$row[date]<br>";
}

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($r2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "$row2[id]\t\t\t$row2[text]\t\t\t$row2[date]<br>";
}
```